# Extrude circle wrong shape

Tags: modeling, extrude

I'm following a tutorial step by step and I really don't understand why is the circle I get by extruding flattened along Z axis.

What I'm trying to do:

[image]

What I get:

[image]

Any advice please?

Comment: Hello :). This looks more like *Extruding along normals* (it's right next to standard extrude tool).

Comment: @JachymMichal it worked, thank you!